# How to calculate time ordered Exponential (special case of rotation matrix)

Tags: exponential-function, matrix-equations, exponentiation, matrix-calculus, matrix-exponential

I have the following problem
$$
\dot{R}(t)=R(t)
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & -\cos{t} \\
0 & 0 & -\sin{t} \\
\cos{t} & \sin t & 0
\end{pmatrix}
\equiv R(t) A(t), \quad R(0)=\mathbb{1}.
$$
Basicly, I need to compute time orderd exponential. I was thinking of formula
$$ R(t) = e^{\int_0^{t}A(\tau)d\tau},$$
but it turned out that $[A(t), A(t')]\neq 0$. So, the only way is to use general formula
$$
\begin{equation}
R(t) = \mathcal{T}\{ e^{\int_0^{t} A(\tau) d\tau}\},
\end{equation}
$$
where $\mathcal{T}$ denotes time-ordering,

$$\mathcal{T}\{ e^{\int_0^{t} A(\tau) d\tau}\} \equiv \sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!}\int_0^t \ldots \int_0^t \mathcal{T}\{A(\tau_1)  \ldots A(\tau_n)  \}.$$
I wonder, is there any way to do it in this general case? i also have the following information about this system

- The eigen values of $A(t)$ are $i, -i, 0$ and corresponding eigen vectors are
  $$
  \begin{pmatrix}
  i\cos{t} \\ 
  i\sin t \\
  1
  \end{pmatrix}, 
  \begin{pmatrix} 
  -i\cos{t} \\
   -i\sin t \\
  1
  \end{pmatrix}, 
  \begin{pmatrix}
  i\tan{t} \\
  1\\
  0
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
- $A(t) = \cos{t} A_1 + \sin t A_2$, where
  $$
  A_1 =
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0\\
  1 & 0 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad A_2 = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}, \quad A_3 = 
  \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 
  \end{pmatrix}
  $$
  are generators of Lie algebra $\mathfrak{so}(3)$.

Comment: diagonalize $A(t)$ with orthogonal matrices and integrate the diagonal of eigenvalues

Comment: @Exodd Can you please explain more precisely? As far as I understand, diagonalization of $A(t)$ mean the following: $A(t) = P(t) \Lambda P(t)^T$, but the system will change too: $\dot{R}(t)=R(t)P(t) \Lambda P(t)^T \Rightarrow P(t)^T\dot{R}(t) P(t)= P(t)^TR(t)P(t) \Lambda$, but what is next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\z{\zeta}
\def\e{{\cal E}}
\def\a{\alpha} \def\b{\beta} \def\l{\lambda}
\def\o{{\tt1}} \def\p{\partial}
\def\BR#1{\left[#1\right]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\unskew#1{\operatorname{unskew}\LR{#1}}
\def\skew#1{\operatorname{skew}\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\operatorname{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\qif{\quad\iff\quad}
\def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\m#1{\left[\begin{array}{r}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\mc#1{\left[\begin{array}{c}#1\end{array}\right]}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\CLR#1{\c{\LR{#1}}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\gradLR#1#2{\LR{\grad{#1}{#2}}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|}
$It is well known that a rotation matrix can be constructed from a skew-symmetric matrix
which in turn can be constructed from a vector
$$\eqalign{
R &= \exp(B),\quad
B = \m{
0 & -b_3 & b_2 \\
b_3 & 0 & -b_1 \\
-b_2 & b_1 & 0 \\
},\quad
b = \m{b_1\\b_2\\b_3} \\
B &= \skew b = -\e\cdot b \\
b &= \unskew B = -\tfrac12\e:B \\
b &= 0 \qiq B=0 \qiq R=I \\
}$$
${\large[}\,\sf NB\!:\;\e$ is the [Levi-Civita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levi-Civita_symbol) tensor$\large\,]$

This is pretty standard stuff, but [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1312.0788) contains an amazing formula
$$\eqalign{
Y &= \fracLR{bb^T+(R^T-I)B}{\frob{b}^2} \qiq
\grad Rb = -R\cdot\e\cdot Y \\
}$$
which can be applied to your problem
$$\eqalign{
\dot R = \gradLR Rb\cdot\dot b
 = R\cdot\CLR{-\e\cdot Y\cdot\dot b}
 = R\:\c{\skew{Y\dot b}}
 \,\equiv\, R\c{A}
\\
}$$
This reduces your problem to
$$\eqalign{
&{Y\dot b} = \unskew A = a \;\equiv\; \m{\sin t\\-\cos t\\0\;\;\;} \\
&\dot b = Y^{-1} a,\qquad b(0) = 0 \\
}$$
Your original problem is a matrix-valued ODE. Worse, it requires special processing to maintain the orthogonality of $R$ after **every** time-step.

The reduced equation is a simple (non-stiff) vector ODE with no orthogonality constraints.

Better yet, an explicit formula exists for the matrix inverse
$$\eqalign{
&Y^{-1} = I \;+\; \tfrac12 B \;+\; \z B^2 \\
&\b = \frob b,\qquad
\z = \fracLR{{\o-\cos\b}-\tfrac12\b\sin\b}{{\b^2-\b^2\cos\b}} \\
\\
&\lim_{\b\to0}\: \z B^2 \,=\; 
\lim_{\b\to0}\, B = 0 \qiq
\lim_{\b\to0}\:  Y^{-1} = I \\
}$$
The formula for $Y^{-1}$ has a nice limit at $\b=0,$ however $Y$
is singular at other points where $\b$ is a multiple of $2\pi.$

Similar formulas exist for $\LR{R,Y}$ in terms of $B$
$$\eqalign{
&R = \LR{I+\l B+\mu B^2},\qquad\quad
Y = \LR{I-\mu B+\nu B^2} \\
&\l = \fracLR{\sin\b}{\b},\quad
\mu=\fracLR{\o-\cos\b}{\b^2},\quad
\nu=\fracLR{\o-\l}{\b^2} \\
&\lim_{\b\to0}\: \left\{\l,\,\mu,\,\nu,\,\z\right\}
 \,=\; \Big\{\o,\,\tfrac12,\,\tfrac16,\,\tfrac1{12}\Big\} \\
}$$
and these are stable for all values of $\b$